# Inequality relation between $l^2$ and $l^\infty$ metrics

Tags: inequality, metric-spaces

I'm trying to show that:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}d_{l^2}(x,y)\leq d_{l^{\infty}}(x,y)\leq d_{l^2}(x,y)$

where $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and $d_{l^2}(x,y):=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-y_i)^2}$ and $d_{l^\infty}(x,y):=\sup\{|x_i-y_i|:1\leq i\leq n\}$.

I've already shown that $d_{l^2}(x,y)\leq d_{l^1}(x,y)\leq\sqrt{n}\ d_{l^2}(x,y)$, where $d_{l^1}(x,y):=\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i-y_i|$ but from this and Cauchy-Schwarz inequality the only thing I've managed to get is $d_{l^2}(x,y)\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}d_{l^\infty}(x,y)$.

So, I'd appreciate any comment/hint about how to prove these two inequalities.

Comment: No need for Cauchy-Schwarz. For the first inequality, note that $\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-y_i)^2}\leq \sqrt{n\max_{i} (x_i-y_i)^2}$. Conclude from there. For the second, observe that $\vert x_i-y_i\vert = \sqrt{(x_i-y_i)^2}\leq \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-y_i)^2}$.

Comment: @user293121 Thank you very much; if you'll write your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll demonstrate the norm inequalities for $$\lVert x \rVert_2^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$$
and 
$$
\lVert x \rVert_\infty = \sup \{\lvert x_i \rvert \mid 1 \leq i \leq n \}.
$$
They're the same, but this is a bit easier on the eye. Now notice that for each $i$, we have $x_i^2 \leq \lVert x \rVert_\infty^2$. So if we sum over $i$ in this inequality, we find $ \lVert x \rVert_2^2 \leq n \lVert x \rVert_\infty^2$, which is precisely the first inequality.

For the second equality, notice that there exists an $i$ for which $\lvert x_i \rvert = \lVert x \rVert_\infty$. In other words
$$
\lVert x \rVert_\infty^2 = x_i^2 \leq \sum_{j=1}^n x_j^2 = \lVert x \rVert_2^2.
$$
And there you have your second inequality.